# odbcconnection in ADO.NET does not contain a definition for executereader

Tags: ado.net

While creating [ODBC reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in ADO.NET, as shown below:

```
//using bla bla bla
using System.Data.Odbc;
//some code
OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//rest of the code
```

I get an error:

> OdbcConnection does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteReader' and no extension method 'ExecuteReader' accepting a first argument of type 'OdbcConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am 100% sure I am missing no using directive nor assembly reference, I've added it myself, so why wouldn't it recognize the method?

Edit: full backend code and aspx code:

Backend C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;



namespace WebApp1
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnct = new SqlConnection("Server=x.x.x.x;User ID=xx;Password=xx;Database=xxxx;"))
            {
                try
                {

                    cnct.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select codcli from client", cnct))
                    {

                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            string code = rdr.GetString(1);
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

ASPX page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp1.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table runat="server">

    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr class="Header">
                <td>Code</td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("code") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

PS: I am sorry for not including the whole code from the beginning, as I am new to StackOverFlow, thank you for being patient with me

Comment: This is not about ODBC nor SQL, but about ADO.NET... And you haven't provided enough of your code for anyone to say why the `ExecuteReader` extension method you say you've added isn't recognized.

Comment: I left my computer at work, when I come back monday I'll send the integrity of the code

Comment: @TallTed  I updated my answer, included backend code and aspx code